# Is left-of-mean cdf of exponential distribution greater than that of a gamma distribution?

Tags: gamma-distribution

Edited to restrict one of the gamma distributions to be an exponential distribution, and to force both means to 1.0, and to add wolfram alpha links:

I have two distributions, both with mean 1, and I want to compare their cdfs when $0 \lt x \lt 1$.  One of the distributions is exponential, and the other distribution is gamma.  I think that in the $0 \lt x \lt 1$ domain, the cdf of the exponential distribution is always at least as big as that of the gamma distribution, but I have not yet been able to prove it.

The exponential distribution of interest is completely specified by its mean of 1.0, and it can be seen for example [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exponential+distribution%281%29) or [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma+distribution%281%2C1%29) using wolfram alpha.

The gamma distribution of interest is forced to have mean 1.0 but it has an extra degree of freedom compared to the exponential distribution.  I want the gamma distribution to be the distribution with mean 1.0 that you get by summing $k \ge 1$ i.i.d exponential distributions each with mean $1 / k$.  Using wolfram alpha's notation this can be seen here (broken link).  Notice that when $k=1$ the gamma distribution is equal to the exponential distribution with mean 1.0, and that in general its cdf is $\Pr(X \le x) = Q(k, 0, k x)$.

This wolfram alpha plot (broken link) shows that for a few $k$ and for $x \in (0,1)$, the cdf seems to increase as a function of $x$ and to decrease as a function of $k$.  I would like to be able to prove the monotonicity in $k$; the monotonicity in $x$ is just a result of the definition of a cdf.  Note that the monotonicity in $k$ does not continue (broken link) when $x \ge 1$.

Comment: What have you done to try to answer this question?  Have you, for instance, plotted some CDFs for a few values of $k$?

Comment: @whuber: yes I played around with wolfram alpha and it seems legit.  But I couldn't find a way to prove it...

Comment: I get a different answer, so I must be misinterpreting the question. I find that the CDFs to the left of the mean all overlap, so no one is consistently greater or less than another (there is no stochastic dominance). If that's not what you meant, then what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @whuber: I rewrote it in a way that I hope is clearer.  Feel free to fix the links that I deliberately broke so that I would have few enough to not be treated as spam.

Comment: Thanks.  If you plot, say, the CDFs for $k=1,2,3$ simultaneously, the answer ought to be clear.

Comment: @whuber: I agree that the answer can be guessed by looking at the plots, but I would like to find a more analytical argument.

Comment: **Related**: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104413/tail-bound-for-poisson-random-variable/104591#104591

Comment: This is a little bizarre. The answer to your updated question is affirmative and I've given a proof (just a few hours ago) to the MathOverflow question at the link. The question there is stated differently, but is equivalent. Are you two related somehow? :-)

Comment: @cardinal: I was indeed inspired by the mathoverflow question, but I'm not the mathoverflow OP.

Comment: Hi gam, yes, I realized you were unlikely to be the OP on MO (given the OP there identifies himself in his profile), but I thought there might be a connection given the similarity in the questions. Would you like me to post a reformulation of that answer here?

Comment: Also, I think if you register your account, you should be able to post the additional links. Cheers. :-)

Comment: Gam, ok; but, you should accept the best answer you receive! My question was more regarding whether it was beneficial to you to have a slight reformation (framed as a more direct response to your post than the MO one), having already presumably seen the answers on MO. :-) I'll plan on going ahead and posting something within a few hours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to your monotonicity conjecture is **affirmative**. It admits a somewhat sneaky proof and allows us to conclude something about the Poisson distribution in the
process. This is what we explore below.

**The picture**

The question asks whether the cdfs decrease pointwise as $n$ increases
for each $x$ to the left of the vertical line $x=1$.

[image: Gamma cdfs]

**The math**

Let's start with a restatement of the question. First, if $\renewcommand{\Pr}{\mathbb P}\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm d}T \sim
\mathrm{Exp}(1)$, then it's easy to see that $T/n \sim
\mathrm{Exp}(n)$. So, we can rewrite a [$\Gamma(n,n)$ random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Characterization_using_shape_.CE.B1_and_rate_.CE.B2)
$S_n$ as $S_n = (T_1 + \cdots + T_n)/n$ where $T_i$ is a sequence of
iid $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ random variables. Instead of asking whether the
cdf decreases pointwise as a function of $n$ for each $0 < x < 1$, we
can ask whether the survival distribution *increases*
pointwise. Hence, we have the following equivalent question.

> **Equivalent question**: Let $T_1, T_2,\ldots$ be an iid sequence of   $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$ random variables and let $S_n = T_1 + \dots +  T_n$. Then, is it true that, for all fixed $x \in (0,1)$, $$ \Pr( S_{n+1} > (n+1) x ) \geq \Pr(S_n > n x) \,? $$

*Proof*. The key idea here is to **divide and conquer**. We need to somehow compare the events $\{S_{n+1} > (n+1)x\}$ and $\{S_n > nx\}$. To that end, notice that
$$
\Pr(S_{n+1} > (n+1)x) = \Pr(S_{n+1} > n x) - \Pr(nx \leq S_{n+1} \leq (n+1)x) \>.
$$
We are halfway there. To deal with the remaining part, observe that
$$
\{S_{n+1} > n x\} = \{S_n > n x\} \cup \{S_n \leq n x, T_{n+1} > nx - S_n \} \>,
$$
and the two events on the right-hand size are disjoint. So,
$$
\Pr(S_{n+1} > (n+1)x) = \Pr(S_n > n x) + \Pr(S_n \leq nx, T_{n+1} > nx - S_n) - \Pr(nx \leq S_{n+1} \leq (n+1)x) \>.
$$

If we can show the second probability is greater than the third, we are done. To do this, we'll first find an explicit value for the second probability and then find an upper bound for the third.

(*Second term*.) $S_n$ and $T_{n+1}$ are independent, so to find $\Pr(S_n \leq nx, T_{n+1} > nx - S_n)$, we need only integrate over the
region of interest. This is
$$
\Pr(S_n \leq nx, T_{n+1} > nx - S_n) = \int_0^{nx} \int_{nx-s}^\infty
e^{-t} \frac{s^{n-1}e^{-s}}{(n-1)!} \, \d t \, \d s  =
\frac{e^{-nx}(nx)^n}{n!} \>.
$$

(*Third term*.) This step is more involved, but still employs only elementary tools. Using the density of $S_{n+1}$, we have
$$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm d}
\Pr(nx \leq S_{n+1} \leq (n+1)x )= \int_{nx}^{(n+1)x} \frac{u^n
e^{-u}}{n!} \,d u = \frac{e^{-nx} (nx)^n}{n!} x \int_0^1 (1+v/n)^n
e^{-xv} \d v
$$
where we've obtained the integral on the far right by using the substitution $v =
(u-nx)/x$. Now $(1+v/n)^n < e^v$ for all $n$ and so
$$
\int_0^1 (1+v/n)^n e^{-xv} \d v < \int_0^1 e^{(1-x) v} \d v =
\frac{e^{1-x} - 1}{1-x} \leq \frac{1}{x} \>,
$$
where the last step follows from the fact that $e^{1-x} < x^{-1}$ for
all $x \in (0,1)$. So,
$$
\Pr(nx \leq S_{n+1} \leq (n+1)x ) < \frac{e^{-nx}(nx)^n}{n!} \>. 
$$

But, this last quantity is the same as the second term! Putting the three pieces together, we get
$$
\Pr(S_{n+1} > (n+1)x ) > \Pr(S_n > n x) \>,
$$
for each $x \in (0,1)$, which is what we set out to prove.

**A consequence**

The appearance of the term $\frac{e^{-nx}(nx)^n}{n!}$ strongly hints
that there is a relation to the Poisson hiding in here. Indeed, the
proof implies the following.

> **Proposition**: Let $X_{n\lambda} \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(n\lambda)$   for $\lambda \in (0,1)$. Then $$ \Pr(X_{n\lambda} < n) \geq e^{-\lambda} \>. $$

Indeed, this was the original context in which I recently gave an equivalent
proof [in this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104413/tail-bound-for-poisson-random-variable/104591#104591).

Answer (score 1):

An analytical proof might be quite difficult to obtain. The CDF of a gamma distribution fixed to have mean 1 is $P(k,kx) = \frac{\gamma\left(k,kx\right)}{\Gamma\left(k\right)}$ and you want to show for $0 \le x \le 1$ and $k > 0$ that

$$
\frac{dP\left(k,kx\right)}{dk} \ge 0
$$

But this works out as being fairly horrible:

$$
\frac{dP\left(k,kx\right)}{dk} = - \frac{x \operatorname{\gamma}\left(k, k x\right) \operatorname{\psi}\left(k x\right)}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(k x\right)} + \frac{\frac{x \left(k x\right)^{k -1}}{e^{k x}} - \operatorname{log}\left(k x\right) \operatorname{\Gamma}\left(k, k x\right) + \operatorname{\Gamma}\left(k\right) \operatorname{\psi}\left(k\right) + {G_{2, 3}^{3, 0}\left.\left(\begin{matrix} 1, 1 \\0, 0, k  \end{matrix} \right| {k x} \right)}}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(k x\right)}
$$

where $\psi(x)$ is the digamma function and $G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left.\left(\begin{matrix} a_1,\ldots,a_p \\ b_1,\ldots, b_q \end{matrix} \right| z \right)$ is the [Meijer G-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function).

I'm not saying it's impossible to prove the inequality but it looks like an awful lot of work!

FYI the differential was calculated using Python 2.7 and the SymPy library.

PS there may be other ways to prove this, for example you could try expanding $P(k,kx)$ into its integral form and working from there

Comment: Please see the comments to the OP. :)

Comment: This analysis should help readers appreciate what @cardinal has achieved in his answer.